# Entity Framework Core database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I thought that I would learn to use ASP.NET Core, instead of what I am used to, ASP.NET, because Microsoft won't update ASP.NET anymore.

But I already got problems...

My problem is that I want to connect to my localdb file, and make this code-first table, but I get an error

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext.

even though I have a connection string for it:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=api;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
```

And I do include it in the startup, that it should use that connection string:

```
services.AddDbContext<UserContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

My table class is like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my Context:

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I found out! You can use EF 6.3 and newer, instead of core, because they are crossplatform now.

Answer (score 1):

your UserContext should have public constructor which accepts a DbContextOptions and pass it to the base constructor .